# Count the squares in the grid

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, count, logic

I have a scenario in which I have a grid with dots. For example in the below case of m X n (i.e. 5 X 6) grid, let's say top left is 0,0 (first row, first column). Dots (1,1) , (1,3), (1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1) are missing.

I need to find the number of squares. Each side of the square should have dots filled. So below the answer would be 4 (which also includes the outer big square). So my question is
A) What is the best way to represent an input to this problem and
B) What is the algorithm to find the squares.

Squares can be enclosed within another. All squares need be counted.

```
......
. .  .
...  .
. ....
......
```

Below is the logic I have so far. The i/p is a 2D array of 1's and 0's (1's are the dots and 0's the gap).

```
set count=0
loop i =0 to m //each row
   loop j = 0 to n //each colum
         ifSquareFormedAt(i,j)
              count++
               

 func ifSquareFormedAt(i,j){
     ???? //what will be the logic here?
 }
```

Comment: You don't count size-1 squares in the right bottom corner?

Comment: @MBo , I don't see a square at the bottom right. Maybe I have missed it. Can you please point me to where it is.

Comment: @sam issac Four close points from the last line and previous one form a square. There are three such squares in the bottom row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple algorithm with `O(n^3)` complexity where `n` is rectangle size:

Calculate cumulative sums by rows and by columns, so `R[i][j]` contains number of ones in i-th row from the left upto j-th index, `C[i][j]` contains number of ones in j-th column from the top upto i-th index.

Now traverse through all possible squares of size `k>1` having left top corner at  `[i][j]`

Get row difference and compare it with k, do the same for column difference

```
for all nonzero i,j:
  for k=1..min(width-j, height-i):
    if nonzero(i+k, j+k):
        if R[i][j+k] - R[i][j] != k   //top row difference
           break                     //there are holes in this row between i and i+k
        if C[i+k][j] - C[i][j] != k   //left column difference
           break  
        if R[i+k][j+k] - R[i+k][j] != k   //bottom row difference
           break                     //there are holes in this row between i and i+k
        if C[i+k][j+k] - C[i][j+l] != k   //right column difference
           break  
        
        count +=1   //we reached this point, so all sides are good
```

Python code fives result 6 (outer rectangle is not square)

```
def nonzero(a, y, x):
    return 1 if a[y][x]=='.' else 0

w = 6
h = 5
a = ['......', '. .  .', '...  .', '. ....', '......']
r = [[0]*w for i in range(h)]
c = [[0]*w for i in range(h)]
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        val = nonzero(a, i, j)
        if i==0:
            c[i][j] = val
        else:
            c[i][j] = c[i-1][j]  + val
        if j==0:
            r[i][j] = val
        else:
            r[i][j] = r[i][j-1] + val
count = 0
for i in range(h - 1):
    for j in range(w - 1):
        if nonzero(a, i, j):
            for k in range(1, min(h-i, w-j)):
                if nonzero(a, i+k, j+k):
                    if r[i][j+k] - r[i][j] != k :
                        break      #there are holes in this row between i and i+k
                    if c[i+k][j] - c[i][j] != k:
                        break
                    if r[i+k][j+k] - r[i+k][j] != k:
                        break
                    if c[i+k][j+k] - c[i][j+k] != k:
                        break
                    count += 1
                    print(i, j, k)
print(count)

0 0 2
0 2 3
2 0 2
3 2 1
3 3 1
3 4 1
6
```

Comment: I have a question.  so at position (i,j) we need to find all the squares that is possibly formed. What does R[i][j+k] - R[i][j] != k mean, does it mean the number of ones(or dots) that will be matched with k. How will it find the inner squares that can be there.

Comment: i, j is top left corner. We check all squares with this corner, then go to another corner. Inner squares are not tested, they will be checked later with another corner

Comment: ,ok so the logic is at each top left point (i,j) we check if we can make a square with length  '1 to k' by seeing the count of 1's (or dots) on the 4 sides. correct ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Cumulative sums just help to optimize counting. I can make Python code to check

Comment: This code works  'A minor change -- for i in range(h - 1):'  I get 6 when I run it.  I guess N^4 is the best we can do.

Comment: Oh, really this is **O(n^3)** algorithm ;)  I wrote the first line before decided to change algorithm in my mind